# How to prevent Android from filtering low frequencies ( < 150Hz )

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording

Is there a way in android to avoid filtering low frequencies less than 150 Hz. Is there a standard range for each sound source?

1. CAMCORDER
2. DEFAULT
3. MIC
4. VOICE_CALL
5. VOICE_COMMUNICATION
6. VOICE_DOWNLINK
7. VOICE_RECOGNITION
8. VOICE_UPLINK

I am almost sure that the source will not have any major effect on the frequency. Is there any way to record those low frequency on android phones?

Comment: _"Is there a standard range for each sound source?"_. None that I've heard of. The acoustic tuning varies between different brands and different models (depending on things like form factor, mic placement, type of mic/speakers, etc). The OEMs are free to tune each use-case as they wish, as long as they pass the CTS tests, the operators' requirements, and the legal requirements for the market where the device is to be released. The CDD states that devices should have a more-or-less flat frequency response between 100 and 4000 Hz when recording audio, but this is not mandatory.

Comment: I would agree with @Michael's response to this.  On at least one audio codec chip I have good knowledge of that is commonly used in Android devices, the LPF can be disabled (via ALSA on linux), but the corner frequency is  pretty high (~200Hz) by default (although you can program the filter co-efficients on it).  I thoroughly expect manufacturers don't bother allowing either.

I don't think Google really sees Android devices as ever being a high fidelity audio recorders, so isn't too bothered about this.    Just so you know, Apple, does, and getting down to DC is entirely possible.